# Expand time interval data into days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Suppose I have data that looks like this:

```
interval_id indiv_id   role start_date   end_date
          1        1      A 2006-05-01 2006-06-16
          2        1      B 2006-06-16 2006-10-16
          3        1      A 2006-10-16 2009-10-16
          4        1      B 2009-10-16 2014-04-23
          5        2      A 2007-12-15 2009-10-16
          6        2      B 2009-10-16 2011-07-01
```

But I want data that looks like this (taking the first role interval as an example):

```
interval_id indiv_id   role        day
          1        1      A 2006-05-01
          1        1      A 2006-05-02
          1        1      A 2006-05-03
          1        1      A 2006-05-04
          1        1      A 2006-05-05
          1        1      A 2006-05-06
        ...      ...    ...        ...
          1        1      A 2006-06-16
```

I've already asked and accepted an answer for [how to best do this in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253622/expand-time-interval-data-into-days-in-r). How would I do this in MS SQL?

In forming your answer, assume that there is no NULL data.

Thanks.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021922/using-a-sql-query-how-can-i-select-every-date-within-a-range/23023278#23023278) on how the create a calendar in SQLServer

Comment: While I'm sure you have a reason to do this, I don't think that your database system should be doing it.

Comment: Why not? I need to do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

First create a table of numbers:

```
DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT = 100000;

;WITH
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(@number_of_numbers)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
)
```

Create a variable @MinDate which is the earliest date in the table (or you can pick something like 1/1/2000 etc
Now join your table against that cte numbers table and and you will get your individual dates:

```
SELECT m.interval_id, m.indiv_id, m.role, b.CheckDate 
FROM MyTable m
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, @MinDate) AS CheckDate
    FROM numbers n

) AS b
    ON b.CheckDate >= m.start_date AND b.CheckDate <= m.end_date  
ORDER BY b.CheckDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its not such a good idea... but you could do a cursor over the data you already hace, and use a while with dateadd so that it iterates from Start to end for each record, and insert it where you need it.